# which is the best tool to transfer data from on prem oracle to Azure data lake store

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

i want to know performance prospective transfer data from on prem oracle to azure data lake

ssis is best or data gateway with adf is best

regards,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

It's not a case of which is the best product, but really a case of there are pros and cons for each product and it depends on your business, experience, skills, data, SLAs etc as to what's best.

Here are some example pros and cons I thought of for each product but they are subjective.  Try and think of your own:

**SSIS**

- Pros

  - familiar ETL tool
  - Azure Feature Pack has Azure Data Lake support
  - accelerators like BIML available
- Cons

  - must be hosted somewhere; on-prem / VM / IaaS etc
  - SQL Server license required

**Azure Data Factory**

- Pros

  - cloud-based scalable ELT tool
  - Powershell support
- Cons

  - unfamiliar JSON interface; basic GUI
  - Data Management Gateway required for on-prem to cloud transfer
  - steeper learning curve for new users

See [here](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2017/03/azure-data-factory-and-ssis-compared/) for more suggestions.